# Can you de-fuse an item from an arrow?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Multiple times when fusing an item to an arrow I have accidentally fused the most powerful item for something silly like hitting a balloon. When that's happened I've just immediately reloaded my most recent auto-save, and luckily no harm was done. Is there anything that I can do if I accidentally fuse something I don't want? I've tried just putting away the bow without actually firing, but then the fused item is just lost entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I press <kbd>X</kbd> while aiming, to put away the bow, the fused item is removed and its count is not decreased.
I've tried also swapping the fused item while aiming, and it always reverts to the starting amount. Nothing is lost unless you fire the arrow.
You can also fuse to "nothing", which is the first slot to the left, in that case you will shoot a standard arrow, as-is.

**EDIT:**

After testing, as suggested by OP, if the item fused is a single unit there's a different situation, but the de-fused item it's not lost forever, which actually is moved at the end of the inventory. Re-sorting the inventory reverts everything.

Comment: I thought `B` was the button to stash the bow. Or do you have your `X` and `B` buttons swapped?

Comment: Uhm yep, I swapped them, you are right. I have jump on `B`.

Comment: Ok, well I'll have to try stashing the bow again and see if I missed something. I didn't think that worked for me.

Comment: Which item were you fusing?

Comment: The two items I accidentally fused were a diamond and an ancient blade, both of which were things I only had 1 of at the time. I thought I had tried stashing the bow with both of those to no success, but I also didn't spend a lot of time playing around. I haven't gone back to intentionally try it with something I don't care about yet, so I'll try that later.

Comment: I tested this out last night and also saw that the item disappeared if there was only one of them. However, the item didn't actually go away - it just moved to the very end of the inventory making it difficult to find. I think re-sorting moved the item back to where it was findable. If you can confirm that functionality it'd be good to add to your answer.

Comment: I can confirm, the item is not lost, it's moved at the end of the inventory. Feel free to edit my answer.